# php_fdf.dll won't work in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, fdf

I have the most up to date version on Xampp (5.6.20). I have downloaded `php_fdf.dll` and `fdftk.dll` and placed them in 
`C:\xampp\php`, 
`C:\xampp\ext\php`, 
`C:\xampp\apache\bin`, 
`C:\Windows\System32`, and 
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

I have them each in all of these places because of advice from various other forum posts. In my php.ini file, I have `extension=fdftk.dll`, and 
`extension=php_fdf.dll` with my extension directive as follows:
`extension_dir="c:\xampp\php\ext"`. 
I have even gone into my Paths on my computer's Environmental Variables and added
`C:\xampp\php\ext` as a path.

Still every time that I try to utilize a function, say `$fdf = fdf_create();`, I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function fdf_create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\processing.php on line 3

as well as this in the apache error log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library)
>   'fdftk.dll' in Unknown on line 0 
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'c:\xampp\php\ext\php_fdf.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

I'm somewhat new to programming, so it's entirely possible that there is something simple that I'm just not aware of, but I've looked through countless forum posts, youtube videos and Xampp, PHP and Apache documentation.

Please help! All I really need is to take HTML form data in my PHP script, then put it into a PDF. It seems like loading the HTML data as FDF with the same field names would be the easiest way to do this (as I had trouble getting PDF forms to communicate properly).

Comment: This question I have also posted in a few other spots online. I'm not trying to waste anyone's time, I am just desperate for an answer.  https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=73865&p=250847#p250847 and https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/4gpsbh/help_php_fdf_wont_work_in_xampp/

Answer (score 0):

You say you placed the files in `C:\xampp\ext\php` but extension_dir is `c:\xampp\php\ext`. ie. ext and php are transposed. Is that a typo or did you really put the files in a different directory than specified by extension_dir?

Also, fdftk.dll is probably not an extension. It's probably used by php_fdf.dll but is not itself an extension. I'd comment that line out.

Comment: Typo. I'll try commenting that out. Thanks